# Triangle Coordinate Geometry

Tags: java, android, geometry

I have a triangle ABC inscribed in a circle. Point B is located in the centre of the circle, A and C are two points on the circle.

[image: circle with inscribed triangle]

**Given**

Given AB (length)

Given coords of A and B

Given angle B (angle ABC)

**Needed**

Find coords of C

**What I know**

AB = BC, both are radius's

**What I am using this for**

I am making a basic 3D java game, for android. This will be used for looking left and right, so if you click on the right part of the screen the objects will move around you by adding one degree to angle B.

**The code I tried for finding coords of C**

```
rect.get(index)[5] = (int) ((di * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle-90)))+.5);
rect.get(index)[6] = (int) ((di * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle-90)))+.5);
rect.get(index)[5] = shapes x coord 
rect.get(index)[6] = shapes y coord 

di = radius length 
angle = angle B
```

and I added the `.5` so that when the coord is truncated it is rounded.

My complete code

```
    double di = distance(playerx, playery, rect.get(index)[5], rect.get(index)[6]);
    double side1 = di;
    System.out.println("Side1: "+ side1);
    double side2 = side1;
    System.out.println("Side2: "+ side2);
    double side3 = distance(rect.get(index)[5], rect.get(index)[6], playerx, playery+di);
    System.out.println("Side3: "+ side3);

    double angle = ((side1*side1)+(side2*side2)-(side3*side3));
    angle = angle/(2*side1*side2);
    angle = Math.acos(angle)*(180/Math.PI);
    System.out.println("Angle: "+angle);
    if(playerx > rect.get(index)[5]){
        if(lookdirection.equals("left")){
            angle += 5;
        }
        if(lookdirection.equals("right")){
            angle -= 5;
        }
    }
    else{
        if(lookdirection.equals("left")){
            angle -= 5;
        }
        if(lookdirection.equals("right")){
            angle += 5;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Angle: "+angle);

    rect.get(index)[5] = -(di * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle-90)));
    rect.get(index)[6] = -(di * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle-90)));

    di = distance(playerx, playery, rect.get(index)[5], rect.get(index)[6]);
    side1 = di;
    System.out.println("Side1: "+ side1);
    side2 = side1;
    System.out.println("Side2: "+ side2);
    side3 = distance(rect.get(index)[5], rect.get(index)[6], playerx, playery+di);
    System.out.println("Side3: "+ side3);
    angle = ((side1*side1)+(side2*side2)-(side3*side3));
    angle = angle/(2*side1*side2);
    angle = Math.acos(angle)*(180/Math.PI);
    System.out.println("Angle: "+angle);

    repaint();
}
```

The angles are now working but the X and Y coords 
but

```
    rect.get(index)[5] = -(di * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle-90)));
rect.get(index)[6] = -(di * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle-90)));
```

are getting very large/ small values.  They should stay 'di' distance away from point B.

Comment: The cords I am getting for C are not correct.

Comment: I added a picture according to your description - hope it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED**

It seems that this is a geometry problem!
I haven't tested your code but I guess what you want is **not**

```
rect.get(index)[6] = (int) ((di * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle-90)))+.5);
```

but

```
rect.get(index)[6] = (int) (-(di * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle-90)))+.5);
```

Try to visualise what you are doing and check the identities under symmetry, shifts, and periodicity [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities). The image is turning and reflecting along the x axis with what you are doing now. You have to take care of rounding issues as well. If coordinates are close to 0 the image might not move.

My suggestion is to keep your coordinates as doubles and only round them when you are going to render them into a pixel without overwriting their value

Comment: Thanks, for some reason my angle is slightly off(.02-.1) even though I stopped rounding it.  And then it gets stuck repeating:
`Side1: 101
Side2: 101
Side3: 170
Angle: 114.61556569086147
Angle: 115.61556569086147
Side1: 101
Side2: 101
Side3: 170
Angle: 114.61556569086147`

Comment: That is because you keep rounding everything else. Why don't you use doubles? You can also try printing the coordinates of each point. If you have a point like (100,3) and after the rotation becomes (99.6,3.1) then after your rounding it remains the same and you keep getting the same result. You only need to get an integer value when you have to draw a pixel

Comment: I am using doubles now, I have a new array list that takes the doubles and rounds them to ints and I draw that arraylist.

Comment: Your code worked for the angles but when I tested it, the translated x and y are both really large/ small numbers

Comment: I did not suggest using minus(-) in both equations. I also gave you a link so that you can simplify your trigonometric equations e.g sin(angle-90)=-sin(90-angle)=-cos(angle). If that confuses more leave it as is. Try to understand what each equation does though. Try to learn trigonometry if you don't know already. I know it's hard. Let me know when you make it work

Comment: all I needed to add was +playerx and +playery at the end